When writing a log to a file or table in Access should I keep the connection open
I have a log process in several of my procedures that writes to a file and I would like to convert it to a function in a separate module.
here's a sample:
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim LogFullName
LogFullName = Application.CurrentProject.path & "\Log_" & Application.VBE.ActiveCodePane.CodeModule.Name & ".log"

If fso.FileExists(LogFullName) Then

    Set fileStream = fso.OpenTextFile(LogFullName, 8)   '1 - ForReading | 2 - ForWriting | 8 - ForAppending

    fileStream.WriteLine vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Format(Now, "yyyyMMdd-hhnnss") & vbCrLf

Else

    Set fileStream = fso.CreateTextFile(LogFullName)

    fileStream.WriteLine vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Format(Now, "yyyyMMdd-hhnnss") & vbCrLf

End If

'Do some Tasks and write logs

fileStream.WriteLine "Log Something"

fileStream.Close

If I convert this to a function, my first thought was to append all the lines to a string and then send to the function when the procedure is complete and use on error and/or try/catch to prevent losing logging.
Thinking this would prevent opening and closing the connection to the file so many times and consuming resources.
Is there a better way to do it.
Lastly would it be better to write the logs to a table instead of a file?

I think each log event should be written immediately to file because there is a risk of loss of log data if the program encounters a problem before writing unsaved logs. Also, using a separate text file for logs is a logical choice because it is independent of database file condition.
